# React Native Crashing on IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I made an app for my family that lives in other city and I have a huge problem, I am without the computer with my app and my react native app is crashing when I open on ios. The app load the react native splash screen but crashes. How I can solve this problem? I need to show this app to my family

Comment: Do you have a free or paid membership?  How long since you last built and installed the app?  Apps signed with a free membership only run for a few days before you need to reinstall them.

Comment: Yesterday when I try to open the app that was installed for some days a pop up has apperead (i dont remember the message) so I reinstalled. I don't have the paid subscription. But I reinstalled yesterday.

Comment: It's likely that your provisioning profile has expired and you will need to rebuild and reinstall,  sorry.